# Missing "reupholstery" and "wool" tags

Tags: support, tags

I have a question about my Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange post: [Estimating the amount of wool stuffing needed for a project](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/6448/estimating-the-amount-of-wool-stuffing-needed-for-a-project)

Both seem like they would be pretty useful tags.

Comment: Wool seems like it'd be a good fit, based on other questions. Not sure reupholstering helps it at all.

Comment: From the perspective of what a tag is supposed to do, wool isn't a good one.  It doesn't really provide a clue to what the question is about.  If there is something unique about using wool for stuffing, a wool tag would need to be paired with other tags to provide some context.  In that case, it's better to have a dedicated tag that goes right to the issue, like [wool-stuffing], assuming people would recognize the unique requirements implied.  If we have users who are experts in wool, they may not even be the best sources for a question on stuffing upholstery.  (cont'd)

Comment: The question isn't about wool, it's really about estimating the amount of fill required.  [upholstery], [fill], [filling], or [stuffing] seem like they would be a better tag (none of which the site currently has).  The site has 5 questions about stuffing things (none about upholstery filling), and the act of stuffing them was inherent to the objects.  So none of them had a separate tag relating to the act of stuffing or the stuffing material.

Comment: @fixer1234 Elmy below suggested a more general [furniture] tag and I'm inclined to agree with their reasoning. I also agree that [wool] is probably not a good tag on second thought.

Comment: IMHO, _reupholstery_ would make sense for a tag, as one of the requisite steps in reupholstering is stuffing the furniture’s cushions.

Answer (score 2):

> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.

Maybe a more general **[furniture]** tag would benefit more exotic questions like:

- [Seats - Principles for comfort](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/6348/6316).
- [How to support heavy weights when constructing chairs with cardboard?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/2281/6316)
- [How can I cover my desk chair's seat?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/2289/6316)

It could be used for all kinds of questions about furniture, including questions about upholstery and others like "How to repair the woven seat of a chair?" or "How to sew a protective covering for an old armchair?", where [upholstery] wouldn't quite fit.

You can assume that a person knowing enough about upholstery to answer this question has also some experience with woodworking or the stability of seating furniture. On the other hand, a carpenter who could answer questions about the stability of furniture might have some experience with upholstery as well.

As for a [wool] tag, I doubt it offers much information.

If a question is tagged with [wool], what does it actually mean? The raw wool freshly sheared from a sheep? Or a wool yarn used for knitting? Stuffing material? A piece of fabric made of wool? It's safe to assume that most people are only experts or interested in some of those topics, so a [wool] tag wouldn't be able to guide the right person to a question they could answer.

Comment: If we're not going to use [wool] though, then what about [felt]? Additionally, the [fabric] tag description asks users to include the fabric if known, which is what prompted the [wool] tag in the first place, and on closer inspection, [felt] seems to be the only specific fabric tag. Either way I'd agree that a more general [furniture] is probably the best fit, if you'd like to add that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest [upholstery](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upholstery) as a tag.

Upholstery is a specialty area, and the subject matter experts are likely to be able to answer any question on that subject.  It would serve to attract the right people to answer those questions, and would be an intuitive search term for people with upholstery-related questions.  It's a "Goldilocks" tag, not too broad and not too narrow in scope.

[reupholstery](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reupholstery), as suggested in the question, is a facet of upholstery; basically upholstery repair or upholstering again.  It doesn't make sense to dedicate a tag to that rather than the more general subject that includes it.

[furniture](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/furniture), as suggested by Elmy, seems too broad to me.  Furniture covers topics like

- the materials and techniques for making and repairing the structure (wood, metal, plastic, cardboard, etc.; as well as other tangential aspects); not only are structural designs a separate subject area, it could well be different people who could answer questions about the different structural materials.  Perhaps [furniture-framing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/furniture-framing) might warrant a dedicated tag if there was any volume of those questions.  Non-traditional furniture construction might also merit dedicated tags if there are enough questions, like [pvc-pipe-furniture](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pvc-pipe-furniture) or [cardboard-furniture](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardboard-furniture). I'm not suggesting creating these tags, they're just examples of what might be an appropriate scope.
- the covering methods and materials other than upholstery (which can vary widely).
- upholstery methods and materials for both the cover and the fill (the dedicated tag I'm suggesting here).
- cleaning, treatment, and repair of the covering.
- etc.

Nobody is an expert in all of those facets.  For example, someone who makes plastic lawn furniture is a furniture expert, but they wouldn't be expected to answer a question on wool as an upholstry stuffing material.